# How do I measure maintaining a positive question record?

Tags: support, badges, asking-questions

Since I am 6/5 on this badge, I guess I am not qualified for "maintain a positive question record". But is that measured?

[image]

Comment: You have 19 questions and 8 of them have a positive record. You need to have at least 50% of your questions received positively (score of 1 or greater).

Comment: You have 22 questions, 4 of which are deleted <= 0, so you'll need 11 positively scored.